# Validation accuracy stuck after reacing 90%

Tags: tensorflow, keras, classification

[image]

I am using transfer learning technique for medical image classification. However, model start to overfit after reaching 88-89%. I used spatial droupout , augmentation but didn't help. I want to achieve good accuracy. I appreciate help from experts. 
Thank you

Comment: Can you share the code of your model?

Comment: @Shubham Panchal,, i used EfficientNet and just transfer learning. You can see here. https://github.com/SahadevPoudel/Medical-image-classification/blob/master/Diff_dataloading_eficientnet.ipynb

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to try some different models.  You can apply many standard AI and data science techniques to overlapping business problems.  Model selection is the process of deciding which techniques are best suited to solve your problem.  It follows a process of experimentation that depends on your data.  Most likely, you can apply multiple models to expose insights into your business problem.

See the two links below for some ideas of how to proceed.

https://github.com/ASH-WICUS/Notebooks/blob/master/Accuracies%20of%20Different%20Classifiers%20-%20Wine.ipynb

https://github.com/ASH-WICUS/Notebooks/blob/master/Accuracies%20of%20Different%20Regressors%20-%20Housing%20Prices.ipynb